# Is the number of isomorphism classes of quotients of a finite dimensional commutative ring over a field finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $A$ is a finite dimensional unital and commutative algebra over some infinite field $k$, what is the number of isomophism classes of rings of the form $A/I$ where $I$ is a proper ideal of $A$? Is it finite?

Certainly, for dimensions 7 and below (by the results of [this paper](http://math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/dimension6.pdf)) the answer to the finite question will be yes, as the number of isomorphism classes of algebras of dimension $n \leq 6$ is finite. Is the number of isomorphism classes of such rings still finite if the dimension of $A$ is greater than 7?

Comment: I doubt any such results would be true. The Hilbert scheme is very complicated and thus, one should expect in general, continuous families. This is not a proof, but given enough time and patience, these should be possible, following the usual ideas expounded by Iarrobino, where the Hilbert scheme is large dimensional and the automorphism group is small.

Comment: MIT did not write the paper. Bjorn Poonen wrote the paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The infinitely many $7$-dimensional algebras described in Poonen's paper are all quotients of the finite dimensional algebra $A=k[w,x,y,z]/\mathfrak{m}^3$ (where $\mathfrak{m}$ is the ideal $(w,x,y,z)$). So $A$ is a $15$-dimensional counterexample.